# element_to_be_clickable not working on radio button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click the one-way button on this [site](https://www.united.com/en/us). I'm waiting for the button to be clickable, but the script times out. Here's the code:

```
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.united.com/en/us")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#oneway'))).click()
```

Thanks!

I made the script work by using the label in-place of the input itself:

```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[for="oneway"]'))).click()
```

But I'm not able to understand why the first approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.united.com/en/us")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='oneway']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.united.com/en/us")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='oneway']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: One-way]

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my question is why does waiting for #oneway not work, but waiting for the label (in your answer too) work? I’m able to select and click #oneway from JS, but doing so from Python times out (element_to_be_clickable)

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect each element i.e. `<label>` and `<input>` in dev-tools and notice, you will see that there is a difference in the co-ordinates where they are located. This could be the reason why clicking `label` works whilst clicking `input` doesn't. Refer below images, you will get an idea.

- **Notice the position of `<label>` where it locates:**

[image]

- **Notice the position of `<input>` where it locates:**

[image]

Comment: From what I'm aware of, Selenium simulates a click action by interacting with the DOM itself, so screen coordinates should not be an issue. I'll be more than happy to be corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Yes your statement about the function of `click()` method sounds rational and correct. For some reason selenium is not able to locate the `<input>` element. Am not too sure about the root cause of this. Let's wait and see if anyone else comes up with any better reason for selenium not able to find the `input` node. Am upvoting your question.